# gerrit review 2.11.3 rejects eGIT push to repository

Tags: git, gerrit, egit

I have created a gerrit server having the following components:

- gerrit 2.11.3  (the latest version supported by Eclipse eGerrit)  git
- git 2.13.3  (the current version)

I have so far successfully:

1. configured gerrit to use our LDAP for HTTP authentication

> [gerrit]
> basePath = /dummysome/data/gerrit2
> canonicalWebUrl = http://build.ct.dummyserver.co.za:8081/
> [database]
> type = oracle
> hostname = localhost
> port = 1521
> instance = gerritdb
> username = gerrit2
> [index]
> type = LUCENE
> [auth]
> type = LDAP
> gitBasicAuthPolicy = LDAP
> [ldap]
> server = ldap://dc1.ct.dummyserver.co.za
> username = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=ct,dc=dummyserver,dc=co,dc=za
> accountBase = ou=Staff,ou=osTelephone,dc=ct,dc=dummyserver,dc=co,dc=za
> groupBase = ou=Staff,ou=osTelephone,dc=ct,dc=dummyserver,dc=co,dc=za
> [sendemail]
> smtpServer = localhost
> [container]
> user = gerrit2
> javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-1.b16.el7_3.x86_64/jre
> [sshd]
> listenAddress = *:29418
>
> [httpd]
>
> listenUrl = http://*:8081/
> [cache]
> directory = cache

2. logged on to the gerrit web UI via HTTP using my LDAP username and password (once logged in gerrit shows me as a member of the "Administrators" group)
3. created a gerrit (git) project "dummy" via the gerrit web
   UI
4. cloned the "dummy" git repository via HTTP from the gerrit
   server    into my Eclipse Neon client using eGit
5. added a new test file to "dummy" on my client and committed it successfully

> [core]
> symlinks = false
> repositoryformatversion = 0
> filemode = false
> logallrefupdates = true
>
> [remote "origin"]
> url = http://dummyserver.com:8081/dummy
> fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> fetch = refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
> pushurl = http://dummyserver.com:8081/dummy
> push = HEAD:refs/for/master
>
> [branch "master"]
> remote = origin
> merge = refs/heads/master
>
> [gerrit]
> createchangeid = true

When I push the changes upstream to the gerrit repository I am prompted to enter my username and password (with an option to save it to Eclipse secure store)

However, when I enter the same details as I used to log on to the gerrit UI, I am continually re-presented with the same login form.

Eventually, when I cancel, I am presented with the following error message:

> Can't connect to any repository: http://dummyserver.com:8081/dummy
> (http://dummyserver.com:8081/dummy: not authorized)

On looking in the gerrit server log I see the following error

> 192.168.1.165 - - [02/Aug/2017:19:53:52 +0200] "GET /dummy/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 12 -
> "JGit/4.6.1.201703071140-r"

I notice the error appears in the log at the moment the login window pops up on my client, NOT when pressing  after entering my username and password. This seems to indicate some sort of server mis-configuration rather than an actual authentication.

I really have no idea where to go next with this and I would greatly appreciate any insights anyone may have as to what could be causing the issue.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the push command?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira - thanks. I am using eGit in Eclipse so I just select the "Push to upstream", however I have edited the original post to contain the eGIT .git\config file that gets auto created when I initially clone the dummy repository from the gerrit server. I hope this information helps?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have permissions to push to "refs/for/master".

Check the permissions at:

Gerrit > Projects > List > dummy > Access > Reference: refs/for/refs/* Push

More info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push).

Comment: thanks - The error in the log occurs before I even enter a username and password in so I'm beginning to wonder if this isn't the problem https://serverfault.com/questions/409616/git-refuses-to-send-credentials-over-http (I'm not sure at all how to debug the server side sadly). Just to note also that I have added Administrators to all the "push" privileges I could find in the "All-Projects" project, which I understand applies to all projects

Comment: Are you using reverse proxy? https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html How is your gerrit.config configured?

Comment: nope I'm not. I have set up successful LDAP authentication logging into the gerrit website, however despite trying many different things and fairly extensive reading on the web and I haven't found anything that explains how - from within an eclipse client - to perform a git https push to gerrit that is able to be authenticated via LDAP. I'm not even sure if it is actually possible or whether I'm chasing a red herring trying to achieve it! If you do have any further insights re this I would greatly appreciate hearing them but if not I'm going to give up on this and use SSH Public keys for push.

Comment: Are you able to clone and fetch using Eclipse and HTTP?